# custom generator class

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I have one table (in an Oracle database) which generates the ID for two other tables.

I am using one of table which ID is generated by that table, I have to read it from that table and increment that sequence too.

So please tell me how to write the custom generator table. I have to write that class in a way that every Id which generated by that table I can get.

```
public class MyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor arg0, Object arg1)
                throws HibernateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and JPA already provides a TableGenerator: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html. It's not clear why you would implement one yourself.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the standard JPA table generator doesn't suit your needs, and what your custom generator should do differently. Have you followed my link?

Comment: JB Nizet : I am working on a existing application which using procedures before but now for some reason we are converting into hibernate .previous application has a table which generates the primary key for different-2 table now on the table name basis i have to get the primary key value .I can easily use sequence generator but i have to use that existing table . Therefore i need a custom generator which gets the value from that table on basis of table name and after that increment the value too in the field .

Comment: @JBNizet : can u please tell me how to use the table generator .I am new to hibernate  so i didn't get that clue .

Comment: Follow the link I already gave you, and follow this one: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id-generator.